# How to link internal pages on react native

Tags: react-native, hyperlink, expo

This is the code i want to link to new page

```
 <Text style={styles.login}><a href={'./App2'}>Already have an account?</a></Text>
```

when i click the "already..."it shows
NoSuchKeyThe specified key does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Link` from `react-navigation` for nested linking of screens.

It uses a `Text` component under the hood.

```
import { Link } from '@react-navigation/native';

// ...

function Home() {
  return (
    <Link to={{ screen: 'Profile', params: { id: 'jane' } }}>
      Go to Jane's profile
    </Link>
  );
}
```

[Details](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/link/) Here please check